# Find a state-space model for the plant

Tags: logic, matlab, control-theory, steady-state

Consider the plant shown in the figure,[plant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqola.png). Find a state-space model for the plant.

I know, I have to use the transfer function to get the state-state model. here I have a confusion about the transfer function.is it $\frac{1}{s(s^{2}+1.4as
+a^{2})}$ or  $\frac{s}{s^{2}+1.4as
+a^{2}}$?

Answer (score 2):

Your plant has multiple inputs, denoted with $U(s)$ and $D(s)$, and one output, denoted with $Y(s)$. Writing the blockdiagram out into one equation for $Y(s)$ yields

$$
Y(s) = \frac{1}{s(s^{2}+1.4as+a^{2})} U(s) + \frac{1}{s} D(s).
$$

So for the state space model you could for example use $\begin{bmatrix}u & d\end{bmatrix}^\top$ as the input vector, with $U(s)$ and $D(s)$ equal to the Laplace transform of $u$ and $d$ respectively. Though, it might also be possible that $d$ would represent a disturbance, in which case both $u$ and $d$ would have their own input matrix.